# Error while executing Query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Iam using codeigniter for developing a website.I tried to join multiple tables and got the following error.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `table1`.`value` ASC' at line 4

```
SELECT `table1`.* FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`id`=`table1`.`id` WHERE `table1`.`p_id` IN() ORDER BY `table1`.`value` ASC
```

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/limca/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some values inside `WHERE IN(?)`

```
SELECT `table1`.* FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`id`=`table1`.`id` 
WHERE `table1`.`p_id` IN(?) ORDER BY `table1`.`value` ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass comma separated ids in `where table1.p_id in(1,2,3)` clause

Answer (score 2):

`IN()` can't be empty you need pass the values.

```
`table1`.`p_id` IN('id1','id2')
```